# How come my WAN IP is assigned as a Private IP Address instead of Public?

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat, wan

My WAN IP used to show up as a valid Public IP address something like `43.146.xx.xx`, `5.132.xx.xx` etc. But my ISP recently changed it, and now I am getting assigned with a private IP address of `100.64.76.86` as a WAN IP address as assigned on modem/router webpage, but when I go to [whatismyipaddress.com](https://whatismyipaddress.com) my IP Address shows up as Public address of `128.204.xx.xx`. How is that possible?

Does this mean port forwarding on NAT is not possible anymore? (I have not tried it yet). It is worth mentioning that I no longer able to ping my IP address anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP has switched to [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). The address block 100.64.0.0/10 was reserved specifically for this use.

This does indeed mean your port forwarding settings will now be meaningless. You simply can no longer receive unsolicited incoming traffic.

Comment: "in carrier-grade NAT networks, even though the router at the consumer end might be configured for port forwarding, the "master router" of the ISP, which runs the CGN, will block this port forwarding because the actual port would not be the port configured by the consumer." -Wikipedia.

This is seriously bad, is there any work around to fix this? Will UPnP protocol still work for my devices? it's an important service that I cannot leave disabled.

Comment: you can ask your ISP if you can buy public IP address its common practice in some ISP providers which using private addresing like this.

Comment: @kubn2 So that means due to IPv4 Address exhaustion, ISP customers in same city will have the same WAN IP address as I do at some point? That literally means port forwarding is impossible.

Comment: @Mathew yes they could have the same public address because your isp running carrier grade nat. So like Daniel said port forwarding is impossible because you sits behind huge NAT.

Comment: There are alternatives to port forwarding. See [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: I know it sucks but that’s the reality of today and even more so of the near future. Because proxy/VPN/tunneling services will eventually run out of addresses, too. If you need to provide services, it may be cheaper to rent a VPS at DigitalOcean or the like.